# How to ignore the result from a procedure in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

As per title, assume I have the following:

```
proc squared(n: int64): int64 = n * n
```

Now let's assume I want to call the procedure `squared` but I am not interested in the result.

If I just write:

```
squared(15)
```

I get an error:

```
Error: expression 'squared(15)' is of type 'int64' and has to be discarded
```

I understand that this type of code is a bad practice, and I should explicitly ignore the result.
*Hence, how do I explicitly ignore the result?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write

```
discard squared(15)
```